Animation cuts when i stop pressing :active css
i've  been designing a button, then you press, then appears an ::after with content "copied!"
Ok, while ::after appears there is an animation, that animation triggers with :active property, but when i stop pressing the animation ends brutally, interrupts. doesnt end properly
 how can i stop pressing and the animation ends properly?
 here my code!


* {
            font-family: monospace;
        }
        table{
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px dashed black;
        }
        td, th{
            padding: 5px;
            border: 2px dashed black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        tr td:nth-child(4) span {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #95c1e3;
            color: white;
            padding: 12px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
        tr td:nth-child(4) span:active::after {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: max-content;
            padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
            background: black;
            border-radius: 50px;
            animation: copied 1s;
            content: "copiado!";
            opacity: 0;
        }
        @keyframes copied {
            0%{
                margin-top: 0;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100%{
                margin-top: 15px;
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Server</th>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Jugadores</th>
         <th>IP</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tabla">
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Sin nombre</td>
         <td>1399 / 5000</td>
         <td><span onclick="onclicker()">hub.mc-complex.com</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>      ! SuperCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ !
            Amigos en: discord.supercraft.es
         </td>
         <td>333 / 2000</td>
         <td><span onclick="onclicker()">supercraft.es</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>   1.8-1.21
            NUEVO &gt; 15 REGALOS DE NAVIDAD
         </td>
         <td>189 / 1000</td>
         <td><span onclick="onclicker()">play.zonecraft.es</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>      ! UniversoCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ !
            Chatea en: discord.universocraft.com
         </td>
         <td>5427 / 20000</td>
         <td><span onclick="onclicker()">mc.universocraft.com</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>




I think you'll need a bit of JS to do this properly.

As @A Haworth mentioned, you could consider using JavaScript to play the animation.
Here, we use a copy class to show the ::after element and then remove the class one frame later. This then plays the transition, which is independent of wether the :active pseudo class matches. This means there is no abrupt end.


document.body.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('span[onclick="onclicker()"]')) {
    // Add the copy class to show the `::after`.
    target.classList.add('copy');
    // Go through two animation frames to ensure we are on the next frame.
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          // Remove the copy class to hide the `::after`.
          target.classList.remove('copy');
        });
    });
  }
});

window.onclicker = () => {};
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  text-align: center;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #95c1e3;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 17px;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  content: "copiado!";
  opacity: 0;
  translate: 0 15px;
  transition: translate 1s, opacity 1s;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span.copy::after {
  opacity: 1;
  translate: 0 0;
  transition: 0s;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Server</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Jugadores</th>
      <th>IP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabla">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Sin nombre</td>
      <td>1399 / 5000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">hub.mc-complex.com</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>! SuperCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ ! Amigos en: discord.supercraft.es</td>
      <td>333 / 2000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">supercraft.es</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1.8-1.21 NUEVO &gt; 15 REGALOS DE NAVIDAD</td>
      <td>189 / 1000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">play.zonecraft.es</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>! UniversoCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ ! Chatea en: discord.universocraft.com</td>
      <td>5427 / 20000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">mc.universocraft.com</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



An alternative JavaScript solution could be to use the Web Animations API:


document.body.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('span[onclick="onclicker()"]')) {
    const keyframes = [
      {
        opacity: 1,
        translate: '0 0',
      },
      {
        opacity: 0,
        translate: '0 15px',
      },
    ];
    const options = {
      duration: 1000,
      timing: 'cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0)',
      pseudoElement: '::after',
    };
    target.animate(keyframes, options);
  }
});

window.onclicker = () => {};
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  text-align: center;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #95c1e3;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 17px;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  content: "copiado!";
  opacity: 0;
  translate: 0 15px;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Server</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Jugadores</th>
      <th>IP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabla">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Sin nombre</td>
      <td>1399 / 5000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">hub.mc-complex.com</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>! SuperCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ ! Amigos en: discord.supercraft.es</td>
      <td>333 / 2000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">supercraft.es</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1.8-1.21 NUEVO &gt; 15 REGALOS DE NAVIDAD</td>
      <td>189 / 1000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">play.zonecraft.es</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>! UniversoCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ ! Chatea en: discord.universocraft.com</td>
      <td>5427 / 20000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">mc.universocraft.com</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



For a CSS-only alternative, you could have the element be shown while :active matches and then have it fade out when it longer does:


document.body.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('span[onclick="onclicker()"]')) {
    // Add the copy class to show the `::after`.
    target.classList.add('copy');
    // Go through two animation frames to ensure we are on the next frame.
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          // Remove the copy class to hide the `::after`.
          target.classList.remove('copy');
        });
    });
  }
});

window.onclicker = () => {};
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  text-align: center;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #95c1e3;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 17px;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  content: "copiado!";
  opacity: 0;
  translate: 0 15px;
  transition: translate 1s, opacity 1s;
}
tr td:nth-child(4) span:active::after {
  opacity: 1;
  translate: 0 0;
  transition: 0s;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Server</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Jugadores</th>
      <th>IP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabla">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Sin nombre</td>
      <td>1399 / 5000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">hub.mc-complex.com</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>! SuperCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ ! Amigos en: discord.supercraft.es</td>
      <td>333 / 2000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">supercraft.es</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1.8-1.21 NUEVO &gt; 15 REGALOS DE NAVIDAD</td>
      <td>189 / 1000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">play.zonecraft.es</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>! UniversoCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ ! Chatea en: discord.universocraft.com</td>
      <td>5427 / 20000</td>
      <td><span onclick="onclicker()">mc.universocraft.com</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Woah!!, i didnt know exists too many ways to achive this, i didnt know to, that the translate as a animation, thank you!!, i used the firste option

If you need a clickable element use <button>. <span> should be the last choice of elements, it's made to format text with no semantics. Plus a <button> is focusable so when the user clicks on it, it stays in that state until the user clicks elsewhere. So in addition to the :active state, those styles should apply to the :focus state as well.
button:active::after,
button:focus::after {
  ...
} 



* {
  font-family: Consolas;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  min-width: max-content;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #95c1e3;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: #95c1e3;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active::after,
button:focus::after {
  content: "copiado!";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(75% - 15.2px);
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: copied 1.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes copied {
  0% {
    translate: 50% 75%;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    translate: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Server</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Jugadores</th>
      <th>IP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabla">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div>Sin</div>
        <div>Nombre</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>1399 / 5000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>hub.mc-complex.com</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div>! SuperCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ !</div>
        <div>Amigos en: discord.supercraft.es</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>333 / 2000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>supercraft.es</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div>1.8-1.21
          NUEVO &gt; 15</div>
        <div>REGALOS DE NAVIDAD</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>189 / 1000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>play.zonecraft.es</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div>! UniversoCraft Network [1.8-1.21] ❤ !</div>
        <div>Chatea en: discord.universocraft.com</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>5427 / 20000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <button>mc.universocraft.com</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



